# Parsing Returned JSON

Tags: c#, api

I am trying to print some of the values from the API call to the console, but I am receiving an error I am unfamiliar with:

System.Xml.XmlException: 'Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.'

I think that I might be incorrectly accessing the values returned to by the API, but I am not 100% sure whats wrong

I've looked at a few other posts about this same issue and tried to implement the fixes suggested, but none of them were able to solve my problem. I think mine is unique as my JSON object is different from others I have seen.

```
namespace CarQueryAPI
{
    class CarResult
    {
        public string model_name { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace CarQueryAPI
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        apiCall();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static void apiCall()
    {
        //client to invoke the car query api
        WebClient client = new WebClient();

        Task<String> carQueryTask = null;// Task<string> that queries carQuery

        // url for API (no key required)
        string url = "https://www.carqueryapi.com/api/0.3/?callback=?&cmd=getTrims&make=toyota&model=camry&year=2005";

        try
        {
           //request info from the api
            carQueryTask = client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url);

            string result = carQueryTask.Result.Remove(0, 2);
            result = result.Remove(result.Length - 4, 4);

            dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);

            string model_name = json.model_name;

            Console.WriteLine(model_name);
        }

        catch (WebException)
        {
            // check whether Task failed
            if (carQueryTask.Status == TaskStatus.Faulted)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Call Failed");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

i need the result to e just the model_name of the car being returned from the call so that I can see how to capture the others as well.

The following is some of the JSON object being returned:

```
?({"Trims":[{"model_id":"38988","model_make_id":"toyota","model_name":"Camry","model_trim":"2.4 GLi Automatic","model_year":"2005","model_body":"Sedan","model_engine_position":"Front","model_engine_cc":"2360","model_engine_cyl":null,"model_engine_type":null,"model_engine_valves_per_cyl":"4","model_engine_power_ps":"152","model_engine_power_rpm":"5600","model_engine_torque_nm":"218","model_engine_torque_rpm":"4000","model_engine_bore_mm":"88.5","model_engine_stroke_mm":"96.0","model_engine_compression":"9.6:1","model_engine_fuel":null,"model_top_speed_kph":"197","model_0_to_100_kph":"10.6","model_drive":"Front","model_transmission_type":"Automatic","model_seats":"5","model_doors":"4","model_weight_kg":"920","model_length_mm":null,"model_width_mm":null,"model_height_mm":null,"model_wheelbase_mm":"2730","model_lkm_hwy":null,"model_lkm_mixed":null,"model_lkm_city":null,"model_fuel_cap_l":"70","model_sold_in_us":"1","model_co2":null,"model_make_display":"Toyota","make_display":"Toyota","make_country":"Japan"},{"model_id":"38999","model_make_id":"toyota","model_name":"Camry","model_trim":"2.4 WT-i","model_year":"2005","model_body":"Sedan","model_engine_position":"Front","model_engine_cc":"2362","model_engine_cyl":"4","model_engine_type":"in-line","model_engine_valves_per_cyl":"4","model_engine_power_ps":"153","model_engine_power_rpm":"5600","model_engine_torque_nm":"218","model_engine_torque_rpm":"3800","model_engine_bore_mm":"88.5","model_engine_stroke_mm":"96.0","model_engine_compression":"9.6:1","model_engine_fuel":"Gasoline - Premium","model_top_speed_kph":"210","model_0_to_100_kph":"9.4","model_drive":"Front","model_transmission_type":null,"model_seats":"5","model_doors":"4","model_weight_kg":"1465","model_length_mm":"4820","model_width_mm":"1800","model_height_mm":"1510","model_wheelbase_mm":"2680","model_lkm_hwy":null,"model_lkm_mixed":"8.7","model_lkm_city":null,"model_fuel_cap_l":"70","model_sold_in_us":"1","model_co2":null,"model_make_display":"Toyota","make_display":"Toyota","make_country":"Japan"}
```

...etc

EDIT:

Changed some of the code as you all suggested, but now I am receiving this error:

Unexpected end when deserializing object. Path 'Trims[18]', line 1, position 19143

Comment: I might be missing something big, but are you trying to parse JSON as XML?

Comment: Oddly, not only is the `?();` part of the response, but the API's [documentation](http://www.carqueryapi.com/documentation/api-usage/) even says so. I might be missing something else big, but I've never seen that before. (I miss lots of big stuff.) So you've got two steps. First remove the weird extra stuff from the JSON. Second, parse it as JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response you're receiving is JSON, not XML.

First, take the JSON without the leading `?(` and trailing `);` and paste it into [json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com/). It's going to generate C# classes you can use to deserialize your JSON. The results aren't always exactly what you want, but your JSON is straightforward, so you'll get two classes that look like this:

```
public class Trim
{
    public string model_id { get; set; }
    public string model_make_id { get; set; }
    public string model_name { get; set; }
    public string model_trim { get; set; }
    // .. lots of other properties
}

public class CarQueryApiTrimsResponse // This was RootObject - I renamed it.
{
    public List<Trim> Trims { get; set; }
}
```

It names the outermost class `RootObject` because it doesn't know what else to call it. I renamed it `CarQueryApiTrimsResponse` to indicate where it comes from.

Include those classes in your project.

In your sample the variable with the response is called `carQueryTask`. To make it a little clearer I'll call it `carQueryResponseJson`. (I don't know how much better that is, but it says it's JSON.)

You'll need to trim those characters off the beginning and end, so you could create a function like this:

```
string TrimWeirdCharactersFromJson(string json)
{
    if (json.StartsWith("?("))
        json = json.Remove(0, 2);
    if (json.EndsWith(");"))
        json = json.Remove(json.Length - 2, 2);
    return json;
}
```

(I have to allow for the possibility that those characters are there for some reason of which I'm ignorant.)

Now, assuming you've added the [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) package to your project, you can do this, starting with the JSON you've received:

```
// fix the weird characters
carQueryResponseJson = TrimWeirdCharactersFromJson(carQueryResponseJson);

// deserialize the JSON, creating an instance of CarQueryApiTrimsResponse
var trims = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CarQueryApiTrimsResponse>(carQueryResponseJson);

// Now you've got a strongly-typed object and you can access the contents of the 
// collection and properties of each trim.
foreach (var trim in trims.Trims)
{
    var modelName = trim.model_name;
     // do something with it
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I followed the carqueryapi link that was in your provided code, and after removing "?(" from the beginning, and ");" from the end the JSON appears to format correctly. Is there any reason those extra characters are needed? You may need to remove them.

Comment: I agree with you there, it looks like the JSON provided shows basically the same error in a JSON validator :)

Comment: I removed the extra bits from the JSON but now I am receiving a new error when I try to deserialize it

Unexpected end when deserializing object. Path 'Trims[18]', line 1, position 19143

Answer (score -1):

I was able to get what I was looking for from the following changes, I had removed to much from the JSON initially and I was parsing it incorrectly. Thank you to everyone who answered or commented so much! You all helped me a lot!

``
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            apiCall();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

```
    public static void apiCall()
    {
        //client to invoke the car query api
        WebClient client = new WebClient();

        Task<String> carQueryTask = null;// Task<string> that queries carQuery

        // url for API (no key required)
        string url = "https://www.carqueryapi.com/api/0.3/?callback=?&cmd=getTrims&make=toyota&model=camry&year=2005";

        try
        {
            //request info from the api
            carQueryTask = client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url);

            string result = carQueryTask.Result.Remove(0, 2);
            result = result.Remove(result.Length - 2, 2);

            dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);

            var model_name = json.Trims[0].model_name;

            Console.WriteLine(model_name);

        }

        catch (WebException)
        {
            // check whether Task failed
            if (carQueryTask.Status == TaskStatus.Faulted)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Call Failed");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

``

Comment: If you assume that the string has the leading and trailing characters and just delete them, bad things will happen if they stop putting those characters there. That's why I'd recommend checking to see if the string actually begins and ends with them before deleting them.

Comment: Oh man, this is a really bad idea.  Don't remove characters from the output like this - you're setting yourself up for an impossible task if responses ever change.